# Proper Use of TRANSACTION / COMMIT with Mysqli Query and REPLACE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating a project that will regularly need to update around 300,000 files a day in an existing INNODB table of about 110,000,000 records using REPLACE INTO from query syntax. I've been looking into ways to optimize this more and found START TRANSACTION / COMMIT, but I'm not sure I'm doing this right. Is it only best done in a multi query? Currently I'm doing this, and seeing no real benefit:

```
$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$mysqli->query("REPLACE INTO `TABLE1` (field list) SELECT fields FROM `TABLE2`")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$mysqli->query("COMMIT")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a real benefit in wrapping a single query in a transaction. You might probably even add a few milliseconds over head but that wouldn't be noticed with the amount of data you are inserting. If you are really concerned about perforance, reconsider the use of REPLACE

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

This could in many situations result in the REPLACE operation being a lot slower than an [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) type query.

Comment: I have been thinking more and more about that lately, and the possibility of someday running out of IDs, though my primary key is a 20 digit integer... it's not infinite. I just ran the query using INSERT IGNORE, still crazy slow. If I were to use the insert on duplicate key update syntax, and some of the columns updated were in an index... would that still be slow?

Comment: Yes, INSERT IGNORE is the fastest possible so if that's slow, the others are going to be a lot slower.

Comment: Why don't you post another question giving your table structure, your indexes and some queries you run on your table.

Comment: Something might be off with my PHP, I just ran the insert ingnore directly and it was very fast, 19 seconds.

Comment: Maybe a smaller data set. Insert ignore is fast because when there is a duplicate, no further action is taken. with ON DUPLICATE it does an update. With REPLACE it has to delete the wrong and then do an insert.

Comment: I just ran the REPLACE INTO query directly in PHPmyadmin... 62 seconds. Something is weird here. The $mysqli->query() took around 15 minutes to run! I think I've got a different problem here...

Comment: so it seems and a different question is in order.

Comment: did you post a new question on this?

Comment: No, I eventually figured out what was going on. The Replace into command was inserting brand new values, so of course, it was pretty fast, but running the same query again triggered the nasty nature of Replace into... In the end I switched my entire system to insert into.. on duplicate key update syntax. It still takes a while to run, but then again... 110 million rows to deal with!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no benefit performance-wise for a query like this.

You will see the performance gain only if there will be a lot of separate insert queries inside of a transaction.